# Gradle setting sourceSet in child

Tags: resources, gradle

I am new to Gradle and my task is move big project from Maven to Gradle. And there is a problem I need to set sourceSet in wicket module becouse HTML files is next to java files. If I set it in wicket module build.gradle when building it is looking for html files in resources directory, if I set it in parent build.gradle file it works but other pats fails. So I would like to ask if I am setting it wrong or something else.

```
    sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            srcDir 'src/main/resources'
            srcDir 'src/main/groovy'
        }
    }
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            srcDir 'src/main/resources'
            srcDir 'src/test/java'
            srcDir 'src/main/groovy'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess Gradle doesn't like paths both being resources AND codesource. As long as you don't override main{java} it defaults to src/main/java.

There is no way you could move the html-files to src/main/resources? My guess is that the module should work just fine as long as you preserve the same package in resources-folder.

Comment: Thanks for answering, don't know about moving html files to resources, need to ask my manager

Comment: If I understand Maven and Gradle correctly that is the way it should be. E.g. Java-files under src/main/java, Groovy-files under src/main/groovy. That way Maven/Gradle expects it should try to compile all files under that folder. As html-files does not need any compiling, they should reside under src/main/resources. As long as you preserve folderstructure your html-files will be placed in correct folders during compiling. Both Maven and Gradle processes resources before compiling also.

Comment: If it doesn't work you could try different settings from http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html Maybe allSource works?